# estou fazendo a requisição ao um modulo eu altero ele porem quando preciso chamar ele alterado vem o antigo

Tags: python

bom dia, estou precisando de ajuda em um projeto, fiz esse programa para simular, mas o problema em questão é que quando import o arquivo TESTE consigo pegar a variável que eu quero porêm quando altero e espero que a variável venha atualizada mas ela não vem. alguém saberia como resolver?

```
arquivo principal!
from teste import *
while True:
    inputa = input("digite valor da variavel var do modulo teste: ")
    file = open("teste.py","w")
    file.write(rf'var ="{inputa}"')
    file.close()
    from teste import *
    print(var)
    
arquivo secundário!

var = "1"
```

eu importo o arquivo pego minha variável e tento muda-la com a função open e esperava que quando desse o import novamente vinhesse a variável atualizada porem não vem.

Answer (score 0):

parece que o problema está em você ter importado o arquivo, pois pelo que dá pra ver no seu código não há necessidade de importar o arquivo, alem de que quando você importa um arquivo, você está executando ele, ou seja, talvez você possa estar tentando editar um arquivo em execução, então, apenas tire os imports e adiciona a variavel var na forma de leitura do arquivo teste.py:

```py
while True:
    inputa = input("digite valor da variavel var do modulo teste: ")
    file = open("teste.py","w")
    file.write(rf'var = "{inputa}"')

    file.close()
    var = open("teste.py", "r")
    rvar = var.read()
    var.close()

    print(rvar)
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Foi so uma simulacao, tenho outro sistema que eu preciso importar porque é varios dicionarios com dados guardados e precisava ler o arquivo e modificalos sem a funcao open...

Comment: Mas  ou ver se tem como converter um json grande em dict, acho  que da porem daria mais trabalho estava tentando so importar os dicionarios

Comment: Você pode recarregar um módulo quando ele já tiver sido importado usando importlib.reload(): eu vi essa respota em outra... pergunta vou testar pra ver se da certo

Comment: se é um arquivo em json, existem bibliotecas próprias para isso, agora converter em dicionário, eu acho que deve vir junto do json, não sei,  tenta usar o regex pra pegar as informações e mudar pra dict

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver com a biblioteca importlib, importlib.resert():

```
#arquivo primeiro
import teste.teste 
import importlib 
while True:
    importlib.reload(teste.teste)
    inputa = input("digite valor da variavel var do modulo teste: ")
    file = open("teste/teste.py","w")
    file.write(rf'var ="{inputa}"')
    file.close()
    print(teste.teste.var)
    
#segundo arquivo
var = "hello"
```